# APC is behaving weirdly in combination with PHP5-FPM and Nginx

Tags: php, caching, nginx, apc

I've got APC running on my Ubuntu 13.04 Server box for quite a while now. A couple of days ago, something, somewhere went wrong and now it's acting very strangely. I'll lay it out.

- APC 3.1.13 (http://vps.sparrowinspace.com/apc.php)
- PHP 5.4.9 (http://vps.sparrowinspace.com/phpinfo.php)
- Nginx 1.4.1

My PHP configuration files are in `/etc/php5/mods-available`. All of the configuration directories of PHP5 (`/etc/php5/cli/conf.d`, `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d`, etc.) are symlinked to `/etc/php5/conf.d/` which in turn is symlinked to `/etc/php5/mods-available`. If I run `php -i` from a shell I get the config files for `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/*` returned, which should be exactly the same as config files anywhere. The relevant part for my question would be this:

```
apc

APC Support => disabled
Version => 3.1.13
APC Debugging => Disabled
MMAP Support => Enabled
MMAP File Mask => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
Locking type => pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support => broken
Revision => $Revision: 327136 $
Build Date => Oct  9 2012 20:29:11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 1M => 1M
apc.mmap_file_mask => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.num_files_hint => 512 => 512
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 128M => 128M
apc.shm_strings_buffer => 4M => 4M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => On => On
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 7200 => 7200
apc.write_lock => On => On
```

This shows the option `apc.enabled` as On. However, my phpinfo.php (link above), which shows the configuration for PHP5-FPM (from `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d`) shows this option as Off. Thing is, the commandline version of php (cli) and the version that runs on my webserver (fpm) use the exact same symlinked configuration files.

My APC seems to be caching, but it behaves strangely. Before when I emptied the cache and reloaded some pages on the Wordpress installs on my server I would see pages get cached right away. Now, it's stuck on the same Hits and Misses numbers for hours, and I can refresh as much as I want, nothing changes.

The `apc.enabled` option shows as `0` (Off) on `apc.php` as well, but it seems to be doing at least something. There're files in the opcode cache as well as in the usercache. It's behaving strangely and I'm getting a lot of contradicting settings returned from PHP. I'm at a loss here. Here's `20-apc.ini` for good measure:

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled="1"
apc.stat = "1"
apc.max_file_size = "1M"
apc.localcache = "1"
apc.localcache.size = "128"
apc.shm_segments = "1"
apc.ttl = "3600"
apc.user_ttl = "7200"
apc.gc_ttl = "3600"
apc.cache_by_default = "1"
apc.filters = ""
apc.write_lock = "1"
apc.num_files_hint= "512"
apc.user_entries_hint="4096"
apc.shm_size = "128M"
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.include_once_override = "0"
apc.file_update_protection="2"
apc.canonicalize = "1"
apc.report_autofilter="0"
apc.stat_ctime="0"
```

If someone needs any other config files or part of them, I'm keeping an eye on this thread, please tell me.

Comment: So it seems the site (fpm) has *apc* running. But the pages are not cached - you mean the PHP files are not cached for a long time, even if you refresh the page(s)?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain. Usually when I empty the cache, and I visit some pages on my Wordpress installs, I would immediately see the Hits and Misses stats go up, and it would start caching all those pages again. Now, the cache seems stagnant, not doing anything, for hours, then all of a sudden the numbers change, then it does not seem to be doing anything for hours again. When you look at my `apc.php` there seems to be caching going on but `apc.php` as well as `phpinfo.php` tell me `apc.enabled` is Off.

Comment: I just thought of something silly and checked it right away: my `apc.php` page is not being cached.

Comment: Not sure if it is related, nut I noticed something strange with *apc* when uploading the files via *rsync* - I had to add the option `apc.stat_ctime=1` to *apc.ini*, then it seems it works ok. If that fix your problem, I'll make a proper answer.

Comment: I would remove mmap_filemask, and localcache config options and start diagnosis from there ... also, remove anything that is unset or has a default that is acceptable, just during debugging ... also, you might want to have a look at Opcache and APCu (pecl), these are the modern, maintained solutions to these problems ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins and ring0: I'll look into your suggestions later today, and I'll keep you posted. If I switch to Opcache/APCu, am I supposed to use both? And would you advise me to upgrade to PHP 5.5 if I do so?

Comment: 5.5 is barely in beta/RC stage, so cannot really advise you to use that. Opcache provides opcode caching (and optimization), and APCu provides user variable caching. Together, they form the same solution as APC of old. Additionally, on a second look, localcache has actually been removed from APC for a while so doesn't do anything, there's probably others, you really should trim the fat from your configuration.

Comment: I just installed APCu and ZendOpcache and they seem to be running fine. However, both are a little lean on documentation. Any recommended settings for a server running several Wordpress installations?

Comment: For instance: APCu is running (http://vps.sparrowinspace.com/apc.php, used the file from git), but it's not caching anything because W3TC used to control my user caching. W3TC is not compatible with either of these php extensions. How do I set them up in a way I don't have to get a plugin involved and they still cache Wordpress?